# Long equation running into margin (no linebreak)

Tags: equations, vertical-alignment, align, subequations, eqnarray

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{CUIThesisV}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{C2eq61}
\tiny
%\begin{align}\label{C2eq61}
%\MoveEqLeft
MI\left( {{E_i},{E_j},E_k^a,E_l^{ma}} \right) = \nonumber \\
& p\left( {{E_i} = 0,E_j = 0,E_k^a = 0,E_l^{ma} = 0} \right)\nonumber \\
& \times {\log _2}\left( {\frac{{p\left( {{E_i} = 0,E_j = 0,E_k^a = 0,E_l^{ma} = 0} \right)}}{{p\left( {{E_i} = 0} \right)p\left( {E_j = 0} \right)p\left( {E_k^a = 0} \right)p\left( {E_l^{ma} = 0} \right)}}} \right)\nonumber \\
& + p\left( {{E_i} = 0,E_j = 0,E_k^a = 0,E_l^{ma} = 1} \right)\nonumber\\
& \times {\log _2}\left( {\frac{{p\left( {{E_i} = 0,E_j = 0,E_k^a = 0,E_l^{ma} = 1} \right)}}{{p\left( {{E_i} = 0} \right)p\left( {E_j = 0} \right)p\left( {E_k^a = 0} \right)p\left( {E_l^{ma} = 1} \right)}}} \right) \nonumber \\
& + p\left( {{E_i} = 0,E_j = 0,E_k^a = 1,E_l^{ma} = 0} \right)\nonumber\\
& \times {\log _2}\left( {\frac{{p\left( {{E_i} = 0,E_j = 0,E_k^a = 1,E_l^{ma}= 0} \right)}}{{p\left( {{E_i} = 0} \right)p\left( {E_j = 0} \right)p\left( {E_k^a = 1} \right)p\left( {E_l^{ma} = 0} \right)}}} \right) \nonumber \\
& + p\left( {{E_i} = 0,E_j = 0,E_k^a = 1,E_l^{ma} = 1} \right)\nonumber\\
& \times {\log _2}\left( {\frac{{p\left( {{E_i} = 0,E_j = 0,E_k^a = 1,E_l^{ma} = 1} \right)}}{{p\left( {{E_i} = 0} \right)p\left( {E_j = 0} \right)p\left( {E_k^a = 1} \right)p\left( {E_l^{ma} = 1} \right)}}} \right) \nonumber \\
& + p\left( {{E_i} = 0,E_j = 1,E_k^a = 0,E_l^{ma} = 0} \right) \nonumber \\
& \times {\log _2}\left( {\frac{{p\left( {{E_i} = 0,E_j = 1,E_k^a = 0,E_l^{ma} = 0} \right)}}{{p\left( {{E_i} = 0} \right)p\left( {E_j = 1} \right)p\left( {E_k^a = 0} \right)p\left( {E_l^{ma} = 0} \right)}}} \right) \nonumber \\
& + p\left( {{E_i} = 0,E_j = 1,E_k^a = 0,E_l^{ma} = 1} \right) \nonumber \\
& \times {\log _2}\left( {\frac{{p\left( {{E_i} = 0,E_j = 1,E_k^a = 0,E_l^{ma} = 1} \right)}}{{p\left( {{E_i} = 0} \right)p\left( {E_j = 1} \right)p\left( {E_k^a = 0} \right)p\left( {E_l^{ma} = 1} \right)}}} \right) \nonumber \\
& + p\left( {{E_i} = 0,E_j = 1,E_k^a = 1,E_l^{ma} = 0} \right)\nonumber\\
& \times {\log _2}\left( {\frac{{p\left( {{E_i} = 0,E_j = 1,E_k^a = 1,E_l^{ma} = 0} \right)}}{{p\left( {{E_i} = 0} \right)p\left( {E_j = 1} \right)p\left( {E_k^a = 1} \right)p\left( {E_l^{ma} = 0} \right)}}} \right) \nonumber \\
& + p\left( {{E_i} = 0,E_j = 1,E_k^a = 1,E_l^{ma} = 1} \right)\nonumber\\
& \times {\log _2}\left( {\frac{{p\left( {{E_i} = 0,E_j = 1,E_k^a = 1,E_l^{ma} = 1} \right)}}{{p\left( {{E_i} = 0} \right)p\left( {E_j = 1} \right)p\left( {E_k^a = 1} \right)p\left( {E_l^{ma} = 1} \right)}}} \right) \nonumber \\
& + p\left( {{E_i} = 1,E_j = 0,E_k^a = 0,E_l^{ma} = 0} \right) \nonumber \\
& \times {\log _2}\left( {\frac{{p\left( {{E_i} = 1,E_j = 0,E_k^a = 0,E_l^{ma} = 0} \right)}}{{p\left( {{E_i} = 1} \right)p\left( {E_j = 0} \right)p\left( {E_k^a = 0} \right)p\left( {E_l^{ma} = 0} \right)}}} \right) \nonumber \\
& + p\left( {{E_i} = 1,E_j = 0,E_k^a = 0,E_l^ma = 1} \right) \nonumber \\
& \times {\log _2}\left( {\frac{{p\left( {{E_i} = 1,E_j = 0,E_k^a = 0,E_l^{ma} = 1} \right)}}{{p\left( {{E_i} = 1} \right)p\left( {E_j = 0} \right)p\left( {E_k^a = 0} \right)p\left( {E_l^{ma} = 1} \right)}}} \right) \nonumber \\
& + p\left( {{E_i} = 1,E_j = 0,E_k^a = 1,E_l^{ma} = 1} \right)\nonumber \\
& \times {\log _2}\left( {\frac{{p\left( {{E_i} = 1,E_j = 0,E_k^a = 1,E_l^{ma} = 1} \right)}}{{p\left( {{E_i} = 1} \right)p\left( {E_j = 0} \right)p\left( {E_k^a = 1} \right)p\left( {E_l^{ma} = 1} \right)}}} \right) \nonumber \\
& + p\left( {{E_i} = 1,E_j = 1,E_k^a = 0,E_l^{ma} = 0} \right) \nonumber \\
& \times {\log _2}\left( {\frac{{p\left( {{E_i} = 1,E_j = 1,E_k^a = 0,E_l^{ma} = 0} \right)}}{{p\left( {{E_i} = 1} \right)p\left( {E_j = 1} \right)p\left( {E_k^a = 0} \right)p\left( {E_l^{ma} = 0} \right)}}} \right) \nonumber \\
& + p\left( {{E_i} = 1,E_j = 1,E_k^a = 0,E_l^{ma}= 1} \right) \nonumber \\
& \times {\log _2}\left( {\frac{{p\left( {{E_i} = 1,E_j = 1,E_k^a = 0,E_l^{ma} = 1} \right)}}{{p\left( {{E_i} = 1} \right)p\left( {E_j = 1} \right)p\left( {E_k^a = 0} \right)p\left( {E_l^{ma} = 1} \right)}}} \right) \nonumber \\
& + p\left( {{E_i} = 1,E_j^t = 1,E_k^a = 1,E_l^{ma} = 0} \right) \nonumber \\
& \times {\log _2}\left( {\frac{{p\left( {{E_i} = 1,E_j = 1,E_k^a = 1,E_l^{ma} = 0} \right)}}{{p\left( {{E_i} = 1} \right)p\left( {E_j = 1} \right)p\left( {E_k^n = 1} \right)p\left( {E_l^m = 0} \right)}}} \right) \nonumber \\
& + p\left( {{E_i} = 1,E_j = 1,E_k^a = 1,E_l^{ma} = 1} \right) \nonumber\\
& \times {\log _2}\left( {\frac{{p\left( {{E_i} = 1,E_j = 1,E_k^a = 1,E_l^{ma} = 1} \right)}}{{p\left( {{E_i} = 1} \right)p\left( {E_j = 1} \right)p\left( {E_k^a = 1} \right)p\left( {E_l^{ma} = 1} \right)}}} \right)
%\end{align}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Are the files of the `CUIThesisV` document class available online?

Comment: Incidentally, the equation should contain 16 separate terms on the right-hand side, but it currently contains only 15.

Comment: I really think that your equation is badly designed. You should introduce some notations such as to simplify its reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First and foremost, you need to issue an `\allowdisplaybreaks` directive before the start of the 17-line `align` environment. (Don't use `equation`, since `equation` doesn't allow line breaks to begin with.)

I would further like to recommend that you get rid of all (yes, *all*) 106 `\left` and 106 `\right` sizing directives, as they contribute nothing useful, but do create a lot of code clutter. I would also recommend getting rid of (a) the parentheses around the long-ish `\frac` terms -- again, they're not needed -- and (b) the multitude of curly braces that, once again, do nothing useful, while rendering the code nearly unreadable.

Next, I'd insert `\quad` directives at the start of the second of each pair of output lines, and I'd change `\\` to `\\[1.25ex]` at the end of each such pair, mainly to provide some much-needed visual grouping.

However, even with all of these recommendations in place, it's still well-nigh impossible to truly maintain this code chunk once it's written. It's also not straightforward to detect that the equation, as provided by you, is actually missing 1 of the 16 required terms. Moreover, in one expression you wrote `E_l^ma` where it really ought to be `E_l^{ma}`; that's of course nothing but a typo, but the repetitive structure of your equations makes it rather difficult to spot and eradicate them. And, even though it's "just a typo", it still detracts from the overall appearance.

If you're at all able to use LuaLaTeX, I'd strongly recommend that you make the switch, as it allows you to create the equation *programmatically*, by creating for nested `for` loops. I.e., something like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{book} % {CUIThesisV}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\directlua{ % define a Lua function that prints 4^2=16 lines
```

```lua
function Print16Lines ( label ) % argument of function is equation's label
  line=1
  for i=0,1 do
    for j=0,1 do
      for k=0,1 do
        for l=0,1 do          
          if line==1 then
             tex.sprint ( "&\\phantom{{}+{}}" )
          else
             tex.sprint ( "&+" )
          end
          tex.sprint ( "p(E_i=" ..i.. ",E_j=" ..j.. ",E_k^a=" .. k.. ",E_l^{ma}=" ..l.. ") \\notag \\\\*" ) % "*" forbids page break
          tex.sprint ( "&\\qquad\\times \\log_2 \\frac{p(E_i=" ..i.. ",E_j=" ..j.. ",E_k^a=" ..k.. ",E_l^{ma}=" ..l.. ")}") % numerator
          tex.sprint ( "{p(E_i=" ..i.. ")\\,p(E_j=" ..j.. ")\\,p(E_k^a=" ..k.. ")\\,p(E_l^{ma}=" ..l.. ")}" ) % denominator
          if line<16 then 
             tex.sprint ( "\\notag  \\\\[1.25ex]" )
          else 
             tex.sprint ( "\\label{" ..label .."}" ) % last line
          end
          line=line+1
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

```tex
}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  \mathit{MI} &( E_i, E_j, E_k^a, E_l^{ma} ) = \notag  \\[1.25ex] 
  \directlua{Print16Lines("C2eq61")}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

---

Here are the first seven lines of the typeset output:

[image]

---

Of course, if the text block is sufficiently wide, it's possible to change the 33-line equation to a 17-line expression by getting rid of the line breaks before the `\log_2`-terms.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{book} % {CUIThesisV}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably

\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align' env. and '\allowdisplaybreaks' macro
\allowdisplaybreaks   
\directlua{ % define a Lua function that prints 4^2=16 lines
```

```lua
function Print16Lines ( ) 
  line=1
  for i=0,1 do
    for j=0,1 do
      for k=0,1 do
        for l=0,1 do          
          if line==1 then
             tex.sprint ( "&\\phantom{{}+{}}" ) % if on first line
          else
             tex.sprint ( "&+" )
          end
          tex.sprint ( "p(E_i=" ..i.. ",E_j=" ..j.. ",E_k^a=" .. k.. ",E_l^{ma}=" ..l.. ")\\times\\log_2" ) 
          tex.sprint ( "\\frac{p(E_i=" ..i.. ",E_j=" ..j.. ",E_k^a=" ..k.. ",E_l^{ma}=" ..l.. ")}") % numerator
          tex.sprint ( "{p(E_i=" ..i.. ")\\,p(E_j=" ..j.. ")\\,p(E_k^a=" ..k.. ")\\,p(E_l^{ma}=" ..l.. ")}" ) % denom.
          if line<16 then 
             tex.sprint ( "\\notag \\\\[0.75ex]" ) 
          end
          line=line+1
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

```tex
}
 
\begin{document}

\begingroup % localize scope of the next two instructions
\medmuskip=2mu   % reduce whitespace around '+' and 'times"
\thickmuskip=2mu % reduce whitespace around ="
\begin{align} 
  \mathit{MI} &( E_i, E_j, E_k^a, E_l^{ma} ) = \notag \\ 
  \directlua{ Print16Lines() }
\end{align} \label{C2eq61}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Nobody likes to read a wall of text where the really important details are hidden among so many symbols, so I propose a different solution.

```
%\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{CUIThesisV}
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\label{C2eq61}
\mathit{MI}(E_i,E_j,E_k^a,E_l^{ma})=
\sum_{\substack{b_1\in\{0,1\} \\ b_2\in\{0,1\} \\ b_3\in\{0,1\} \\ b_4\in\{0,1\}}}
  F(b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4)
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
F(b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4)&=
  p(E_i=b_1,E_j=b_2,E_k^a=b_3,E_l^{ma}=b_4) \\[1ex]
  &\quad\times
  \log_2\frac{p(E_i=b_1,E_j=b_2,E_k^a=b_3,E_l^{ma}=b_4)}
             {p(E_i=b_1)\,p(E_j=b_2)\,p(E_k^a=b_3)\,p(E_l^{ma}=b_4)}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

This way the inner structure of the formula can be perceived more easily. Maybe you can devise a better name for `F`.

[image]

Avoid too many parentheses and useless braces. For instance the braces around `\log_2` are even wrong. You can see that `\left` and `\right` do nothing useful except producing unwanted small spaces. Note `\mathit{MI}`, because it seems a unique function identifier, as opposed to a multiplication.

Comment: +1. The expression `E_l^ma` should be written as `E_l^{ma}`, though.

Comment: @Mico Thanks! I forgot that one!

Answer (score 4):

Long math expression in the `equation` environment cannot be broken into multi lines. For this you had to use one of `amsmath` environments as are `align`, `gather`, etc.

Since i haven't used document class, instead of it I use `book` (in hope that it default size of the `\textwidth` is approximately the same as at `CUIThesisV`, see if the following suggestion works for you:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{book}%{CUIThesisV}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{nccmath,    % added
            amssymb,amsthm, 
            mathtools}  % added
\allowdisplaybreaks
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}

%\begin{equation}\label{C2eq61}
\footnotesize
\begin{fleqn}
\begin{align}\label{C2eq61}
\MoveEqLeft[0.35]
MI\left( {{E_i},{E_j},E_k^a,E_l^{ma}} \right) = \nonumber \\
    & p\left( {{E_i} = 0,E_j{=}0,E_k^a{=}0,E_l^{ma}{=}0} \right)
\times {\log _2}\left( {\frac{{p\left( {{E_i}{=}0,E_j{=}0,E_k^a{=}0,E_l^{ma}{=}0} \right)}}{{p\left( {{E_i}{=}0} \right)p\left( {E_j{=}0} \right)p\left( {E_k^a{=}0} \right)p\left( {E_l^{ma}{=}0} \right)}}} \right)       \notag  \\
    & + p\left( {{E_i}{=}0,E_j{=}0,E_k^a{=}0,E_l^{ma}{=}1} \right)
\times {\log _2}\left( {\frac{{p\left( {{E_i}{=}0,E_j{=}0,E_k^a{=}0,E_l^{ma}{=}1} \right)}}{{p\left( {{E_i}{=}0} \right)p\left( {E_j{=}0} \right)p\left( {E_k^a{=}0} \right)p\left( {E_l^{ma}{=}1} \right)}}} \right)       \notag  \\
    & + p\left( {{E_i}{=}0,E_j{=}0,E_k^a{=}1,E_l^{ma}{=}0} \right)
\times {\log _2}\left( {\frac{{p\left( {{E_i}{=}0,E_j{=}0,E_k^a{=}1,E_l^{ma}= 0} \right)}}{{p\left( {{E_i}{=}0} \right)p\left( {E_j{=}0} \right)p\left( {E_k^a{=}1} \right)p\left( {E_l^{ma}{=}0} \right)}}} \right)       \notag  \\
    & + p\left( {{E_i}{=}0,E_j{=}0,E_k^a{=}1,E_l^{ma}{=}1} \right)
\times {\log _2}\left( {\frac{{p\left( {{E_i}{=}0,E_j{=}0,E_k^a{=}1,E_l^{ma}{=}1} \right)}}{{p\left( {{E_i}{=}0} \right)p\left( {E_j{=}0} \right)p\left( {E_k^a{=}1} \right)p\left( {E_l^{ma}{=}1} \right)}}} \right)       \notag  \\
    & + p\left( {{E_i}{=}0,E_j{=}1,E_k^a{=}0,E_l^{ma}{=}0} \right)
\times {\log _2}\left( {\frac{{p\left( {{E_i}{=}0,E_j{=}1,E_k^a{=}0,E_l^{ma}{=}0} \right)}}{{p\left( {{E_i}{=}0} \right)p\left( {E_j{=}1} \right)p\left( {E_k^a{=}0} \right)p\left( {E_l^{ma}{=}0} \right)}}} \right)       \notag  \\
    & + p\left( {{E_i}{=}0,E_j{=}1,E_k^a{=}0,E_l^{ma}{=}1} \right)
\times {\log _2}\left( {\frac{{p\left( {{E_i}{=}0,E_j{=}1,E_k^a{=}0,E_l^{ma}{=}1} \right)}}{{p\left( {{E_i}{=}0} \right)p\left( {E_j{=}1} \right)p\left( {E_k^a{=}0} \right)p\left( {E_l^{ma}{=}1} \right)}}} \right)       \notag  \\
    & + p\left( {{E_i}{=}0,E_j{=}1,E_k^a{=}1,E_l^{ma}{=}0} \right)
\times {\log _2}\left( {\frac{{p\left( {{E_i}{=}0,E_j{=}1,E_k^a{=}1,E_l^{ma}{=}0} \right)}}{{p\left( {{E_i}{=}0} \right)p\left( {E_j{=}1} \right)p\left( {E_k^a{=}1} \right)p\left( {E_l^{ma}{=}0} \right)}}} \right)       \notag  \\
    & + p\left( {{E_i}{=}0,E_j{=}1,E_k^a{=}1,E_l^{ma}{=}1} \right)
\times {\log _2}\left( {\frac{{p\left( {{E_i}{=}0,E_j{=}1,E_k^a{=}1,E_l^{ma}{=}1} \right)}}{{p\left( {{E_i}{=}0} \right)p\left( {E_j{=}1} \right)p\left( {E_k^a{=}1} \right)p\left( {E_l^{ma}{=}1} \right)}}} \right)       \notag  \\
    & + p\left( {{E_i}{=}1,E_j{=}0,E_k^a{=}0,E_l^{ma}{=}0} \right)
\times {\log _2}\left( {\frac{{p\left( {{E_i}{=}1,E_j{=}0,E_k^a{=}0,E_l^{ma}{=}0} \right)}}{{p\left( {{E_i}{=}1} \right)p\left( {E_j{=}0} \right)p\left( {E_k^a{=}0} \right)p\left( {E_l^{ma}{=}0} \right)}}} \right)       \notag  \\
    & + p\left( {{E_i}{=}1,E_j{=}0,E_k^a{=}0,E_l^ma{=}1} \right)
\times {\log _2}\left( {\frac{{p\left( {{E_i}{=}1,E_j{=}0,E_k^a{=}0,E_l^{ma}{=}1} \right)}}{{p\left( {{E_i}{=}1} \right)p\left( {E_j{=}0} \right)p\left( {E_k^a{=}0} \right)p\left( {E_l^{ma}{=}1} \right)}}} \right)       \notag  \\
    & + p\left( {{E_i}{=}1,E_j{=}0,E_k^a{=}1,E_l^{ma}{=}1} \right)
\times {\log _2}\left( {\frac{{p\left( {{E_i}{=}1,E_j{=}0,E_k^a{=}1,E_l^{ma}{=}1} \right)}}{{p\left( {{E_i}{=}1} \right)p\left( {E_j{=}0} \right)p\left( {E_k^a{=}1} \right)p\left( {E_l^{ma}{=}1} \right)}}} \right)       \notag  \\
& + p\left( {{E_i}{=}1,E_j{=}1,E_k^a{=}0,E_l^{ma}{=}0} \right)
\times {\log _2}\left( {\frac{{p\left( {{E_i}{=}1,E_j{=}1,E_k^a{=}0,E_l^{ma}{=}0} \right)}}{{p\left( {{E_i}{=}1} \right)p\left( {E_j{=}1} \right)p\left( {E_k^a{=}0} \right)p\left( {E_l^{ma}{=}0} \right)}}} \right)       \notag  \\
    & + p\left( {{E_i}{=}1,E_j{=}1,E_k^a{=}0,E_l^{ma}{=}1} \right)
\times {\log _2}\left( {\frac{{p\left( {{E_i}{=}1,E_j{=}1,E_k^a{=}0,E_l^{ma}{=}1} \right)}}{{p\left( {{E_i}{=}1} \right)p\left( {E_j{=}1} \right)p\left( {E_k^a{=}0} \right)p\left( {E_l^{ma}{=}1} \right)}}} \right)       \notag  \\
    & + p\left( {{E_i}{=}1,E_j^t{=}1,E_k^a{=}1,E_l^{ma}{=}0} \right)
\times {\log _2}\left( {\frac{{p\left( {{E_i}{=}1,E_j{=}1,E_k^a{=}1,E_l^{ma}{=}0} \right)}}{{p\left( {{E_i}{=}1} \right)p\left( {E_j{=}1} \right)p\left( {E_k^n{=}1} \right)p\left( {E_l^m{=}0} \right)}}} \right)          \notag  \\
    & + p\left( {{E_i}{=}1,E_j{=}1,E_k^a{=}1,E_l^{ma}{=}1} \right)
\times {\log _2}\left( {\frac{{p\left( {{E_i}{=}1,E_j{=}1,E_k^a{=}1,E_l^{ma}{=}1} \right)}}{{p\left( {{E_i}{=}1} \right)p\left( {E_j{=}1} \right)p\left( {E_k^a{=}1} \right)p\left( {E_l^{ma}{=}1} \right)}}} \right)
\end{align}
\end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(redlines indicate text borders)

If `\textwidth` is smaller as at `book`, than you can for this equation can locally change `\textwidth` by use `\adjustwidth` macro defined in the `changepage` package.

Comment: I think the large parentheses aroudn the `\frac` terms aren't needed, either for the mathematics for typographic aesthetics.

Comment: @Mico, you are right. I wouldn't use them and consequently increase `\MoveEqLeft` to 1. But I didn't took liberty to remove them.